# Will dynamic compression work without explicitly checking the checkbox for dynamic compression using IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5

I have not installed the Performance features (Dynamic Content Compression) using the Turn Windows features on or Off dialog box for enabling dynamic compression and also not enabled the checkbox "Enable dynamic content compression" using the IIS 7.5 but in the web.config file I have mentioned the following code :

```
<!-- Compression Settings-->
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
```

My question is will the dynamic compression come into play here with the above settings?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without checking the checkbox, dynamics compression will not work.
It can as well be that it's not even installed as feature on the server.